# How do I apply a polygon mask to a video feed in Python using OpenCV?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am creating a security camera parking spot detection system in Python where the user will be able to define the bounds of each parking spot manually in order to be as adaptable as possible. The script that allows the user to create each parking spot's boundaries works great and outputs the collection of shapes as an array of dictionaries, each dictionary containing the x and y coords of each point in the shape as aspects of the dictionary.

I have been able to achieve polygon masks like [image: this] by using the following code:

```
img2 = cap # background image
plain = Image.new('L', (cap.shape[1], cap.shape[0]),0) # plain black image
polygon = [(shapes[i]['x1'], shapes[i]['y1']), (shapes[i]['x2'], shapes[i]['y2']), (shapes[i]['x3'], shapes[i]['y3']), (shapes[i]['x4'], shapes[i]['y4'])]
ImageDraw.Draw(plain).polygon(polygon, outline=1, fill=1)
mask = np.array(plain)
masked_img = cv.bitwise_and(img2, img2, mask = mask)
cv.imshow('d',masked_img)
```

The goal here is to create a separate mask of each shape the user inputs, use image processing and Canny to determine whether or not a car is located in the mask, then move on to the next spot. Repeat this process for each spot and as long as there is a live video feed. I'm speculating that the PIL instructions are interfering with the video feed somehow?

This is my code that I've written so far:

```
while True:
    while i<len(shapes):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        blank = np.zeros((round(cap.get(3)), round(cap.get(4))))
        polygon = [(shapes[i]['x1'], shapes[i]['y1']), (shapes[i]['x2'], shapes[i]['y2']), (shapes[i]['x3'], shapes[i]['y3']), (shapes[i]['x4'], shapes[i]['y4'])]
        ImageDraw.Draw(blank).polygon(polygon, outline=1, fill=1)
        mask = np.array(blank)
        masked_img = cv.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask = mask)
```

Where should I go from here? Thanks!

The code I wrote so far gets me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 843, in Draw
    return im.getdraw(mode)
           ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'getdraw'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my workspace\mycode.py", line 38, in <module>
    ImageDraw.Draw(blank).polygon(polygon, outline=1, fill=1)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 845, in Draw
    return ImageDraw(im, mode)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 62, in __init__
    im.load()
    ^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'load'
```

Comment: No, the issue is that `ImageDraw.Draw` requires an image, not a numpy array.  So, just create a blank image using `Image.new`.

Comment: You already use OpenCV and that is perfectly capable of drawing polygons directly on numpy arrays. Why are you mixing in PIL as well, adding an unnecessary dependency and complicating things?

Comment: needs clarity. you show a trivial `AttributeError` (careless mix of numpy and PIL), but also talk a lot about wanting to detect the occupancy of spaces in a parking lot. which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommended using numpy slicing for image crop due to the computational load of `cv.bitwise_and`. Below is a simple code example.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('top-view-parking-lot.jpg')

while True:
    roi = cv2.selectROI(img)
    print("ROI coordinates: ", roi)
    x, y, w, h = roi
    roi = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    edges = cv2.Canny(roi, 50, 150)

    edge_pixels = np.sum(edges > 0)
    print("Number of edge pixels: ", edge_pixels)

    if edge_pixels > 100: # Adjust this threshold as image quality varies
        print("Car detected!")
    else:
        print("No car detected.")

    cv2.imshow('ROI', roi)
    cv2.imshow('Edges', edges)
    if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Below are examples illustrating the output of the code for empty and occupied parking spots.

Empty spot example:

[image: no car detected]

Occupied spot example:

[image: car detected]

If you have any further questions, please feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: The use of cv2.selectROI(img) in the code was merely for the purpose of demonstrating functionality. The same operations can be performed with pre-defined ROIs, which aligns with your requirement to manually set the bounds of each parking spot for adaptability. If you could provide an image along with the data regarding the parking spots (OP data), I could offer a more tailored response to better meet your needs.